# Process doesn't unpause when receiving a user-defined signal

Tags: c, unix, signals, fork, pause

I'm trying to make two processes cooperate in C. For this, I'm using `pause()` and user signals, as my understanding is, `pause()` causes the program to sleep until a signal is received. I'm doing this:

```
pid_t child = fork();
if(child < 0) {
    perror("Fork error");
    exit(1);
}
    else if (child > 0) { //parent process
    //do something here, then:
        printf("Parent pausing\n"); 
        pause();
        printf("parent received sigusr2\n");    
        //do something
        kill(child, SIGUSR2);
        printf("Sent signal to child\n");   
        sleep(1);
        fflush(NULL);
        pause();
        kill(child,SIGTERM);                
        waitpid(child, &status, 0);
    }
    else { //child process
       //do something, then
       printf("Child sending sigusr2\n");
       kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
       printf("Child pausing\n");
       pause();
       //do something
       kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);

       fflush(NULL);
       printf(frompipe);
       pause();             
}
```

(This might have problems *after* the specific problem I'm showing, haven't gotten there in coding yet). So my current output is:

```
Parent pausing
Child sending sigusr2
Child pausing
User-defined signal 2
```

And it just stops there, as if the parent process wouldn't have received the signal (since it doesn't print `parent received sigusr2`). The program terminates, but a process gets stuck in the background. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a signal handler for these signals? From `man pause`: *pause() causes the calling process (or thread) to sleep until a signal is delivered that either terminates the process or **causes the invocation of a signal-catching function.***

Comment: From the same manpage, `sigsuspend(2)` might be worth a look.

Comment: I thought `pause()` itself caught the signal... Doesn't it?

Comment: The `man` page is pretty clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

@Eugene Sh. is correct: you need a signal-handler function.  The [`pause(2)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pause) says

> pause() only returns when a signal was caught and the signal-catching function returned.

To do this with [`sigaction(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction), add to your program:

```
void sigusr2_handler(int) { /* do nothing*/ }
```

Then, before the `fork()` call, add

```
struct sigaction sa;
sa.handler = sigusr2_handler;
sa.mask = 0;
sa.sa_flags = 0;
sigaction(SIGUSR2, sigusr2_handler);
```

Using `sigaction` means this handler will persist until you disable it (unlike `signal(2)`).  Putting this before the `fork` call causes it to apply to parent and child; [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) says, "A child created via `fork(2)` inherits a copy of its parent's signal dispositions."

With this code, your `pause()` call should return.  If you want to print a message or do something else within `sigusr2_handler`, you certainly can do so, but the general advice I have read is to keep your handlers as simple as possible.

(By the way, I would also add `fflush` calls after every `printf` to be on the safe side while debugging.  I think that shouldn't be necessary, but it can't hurt!)